# Last day of the previous quarter minus 1 or 2 years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the last day for the previous quarter, then minus how many ever years from that.

For example I run the report in  `2019-01-10` then the last day of the previous quarter would be `2018-12-31`. I want to then just minus `2` years from this.

I have this currently:

```
year(CONVERT(date,DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, getdate()), 0))))-2
```

But need output like `2018-12-31` not `2016`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=156f0e5af847563f22c115f438145933)**

If you want to minus 2 years from last day of the previous quarter then -

```
select cast(dateadd(year,-2,DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0,'2019-01-10'), 
0))) as date) As PreviousQuarterLastdayTime
```

OUTPUT:

```
PreviousQuarterLastdayTime
31/12/2016 00:00:00
```

If you want only last day of the previous quarter then -

```
select cast(DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0,'2019-01-10'), 
    0)) as date) As PreviousQuarterLastdayTime
```

OUTPUT:

```
PreviousQuarterLastdayTime
31/12/2018 00:00:00
```